# How to use Repositories inside a custom bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'm building a reusable bundle for Symfony 4, I'm getting stuck every 5 minutes and this time its about Doctrine.

I have been (kind of) following this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-create-your-user-class)

In my bundle I have a User entity and its repository, first of all I created them with `php bin/console make:user` then `php bin/console make:auth` to build a simple login example, it works when all the classes and services are in the `App\` namespace, but I need somethings to be in my bundle, like the entities, and repositories.

When I move only the entity and rewrite the namespaces for both the entity and its repository it works but when I move the repository to my bundle to have both of them in the bundle I get this error:

> The "ExampleVendor\AdminBundle\Repository\UserRepository" entity repository implements "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepositoryInterface", but its service could not be found. Make sure the service exists and is tagged with "doctrine.repository_service".

This is my repository class, its autogenerated.

```
<?php

namespace ExampleVendor\AdminBundle\Repository;

use ExampleVendor\AdminBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordUpgraderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @method User|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method User|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method User[]    findAll()
 * @method User[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository implements PasswordUpgraderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function upgradePassword(UserInterface $user, string $newEncodedPassword): void
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', \get_class($user)));
        }

        $user->setPassword($newEncodedPassword);
        $this->_em->persist($user);
        $this->_em->flush();
    }
}
```

The error says something about an `ServiceEntityRepositoryInterface` but the repository doesn't implement it directly, it extends a `ServiceEntityRepository` which I guess is the one who implements `ServiceEntityRepositoryInterface` so should I inject `ServiceEntityRepository` into my repository? How to do that? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autowiring and autoconfiguring in `services.yaml` does probably not include your custom bundle path. As such, you need to manually configure and autowire your repository:

```
ExampleVendor\AdminBundle\Repository\UserRepository:
    autowire: true
    tags: ['doctrine.repository_service']
```